# XAMPP Magento 2 vendor folder does not have any core modules

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.0, localhost, xampp, vendor

I tried to use Magento 2.3.0 in my Localhost.But vendor folder is not having required modules.Please help why it is happening.

Comment: from where you downloaded Magento 2 ?

Comment: in github for 2.3.0

Comment: Git repository is for developer purpose.

Comment: sorry i am new to magento. can you pls suggest where to download codebase for localhost

Comment: in my answer I gave a link, please click on link. it will redirect on official site. you can download it from here.

Comment: I believe you have cloned the Magento 2 repository. if so, you can run composer command `composer update` and it will install all the required core Magento files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download from official Magento site i.e

> https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

**Note:** You need an active account to download

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you check these docs to get started

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/bk-install-guide.html

In particular you want the easy install

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/zip_install.html

Although xampp does need some extra attention to work

Check this

https://www.simicart.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-2-localhost/